# What is meant by distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I was reading Biostatistical Analysis By Zar and stumbled upon the following:

> Chi square goodness of fit is frequently desired to obtain a sample of nominal scale data to infer whether the population from which it came conforms to a specialised theoretical **distribution**.

I came across this term quite a number of times in a [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/inference-categorical-data-chi-square-tests/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-tests/v/pearson-s-chi-square-test-goodness-of-fit) of the same by Khan academy.

I tried to google it up but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) is not very comprehensible to me.

So what does it mean? Explaining it in a very simple way will be much appreciated.

P.S. I had Mathematics till class X.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution is probably what you're after. The wiki article you linked is something else.

Comment: The term "distribution" has different meanings. I think (given the context) you're referring to the term used in probability theory and not distribution theory (which is the wikipedia link you referred to). That's why I changed the tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic is *probability* distribution.

This expression denotes a function that associates the values taken by a random variable (some unpredictable event that you somehow rate) and a probability that this value is achieved.

For example, the number of tails in a triple drawing of a fair coin gives the distribution

$$
0\to\frac18\\
1\to\frac38\\
2\to\frac38\\
3\to\frac18,$$

meaning that in the long run, you will get one eighth of the drawings with no tail, three eighths with a single tail and so on.

---

The Chi-square test which you mention is a statistical technique used to determine if a given random variable indeed follows an hypothesized distribution. For example, it can tell you if a coin behaves like a fair one. (Technically, this is called a Binomial distribution.)

Comment: `unpredictable even`- did you mean event?

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh: typo fixed.

Comment: I can't understand `triple drawing` and `8` ? Should it be four drawings?

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh: hint: $8=2^3$.